# Subquery in join can't reach object outside of the subquery

Tags: sql, teradata

The following query selects a students names and their highest score for a particular row. The problem is that the subquery in the left join can't be used.
I get the Teradata data error: "Object Date_View doesn't exist'". How can this be fixed?

```
Select name, max_score_today.max_score From Student_View

Left Join Date_view 
ON Date_View.date=Student_View.date

Left Join (
Select MAX(score) as max_score FROM 
Score_View
Where Date_View.start_date=Score_View.date

) max_score_today
ON max_score_today.name=Student_View.name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your correlated subquery up into the select statement, such as:

```
    select name, 
(select max(score) from score_view where date_view.start_date) = score_view.date) as max_score
    from student_view
    left join
    date_view
    on date_view.date = student_view.date;
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the row with the highest/lowest value you better use `RANK` or `ROW_NUMBER` like this:

```
Select *
From Student_View
Left Join Date_view 
  on Date_View.date=Student_View.date 
Left Join Score_View
   on Date_View.start_date=Score_View.date
   and Score_View.name=Student_View.name
QUALIFY -- get the highest score for each student/date
  ROW_NUMBER() -- maybe RANK
  OVER (PARTITION BY Student_View.name, Score_View.date
ORDER BY Score_View.score DESC) = 1
```

I'm not sure if this the correct result, you might have to change the PARTITION expression...